# Clone Team Project within the same Collection TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

I've recently upgraded my TFS environment to 2012 (from 2010) and would like to take advantage of the project management features (ie. agile dev).

The issue I have is the current project has custom templates that cannot be automatically upgraded though tfs' wizards.

I was wondering, is there a way to clone a existing project or branch it so it retains all its change history while being able to implement the new agile templates?

Comment: why not manually upgrade the missing bits? what template did you base the project on originally?

Comment: I have no problem losing the old templates for work items.  That is a different issue in itself. I am just wondering if it's possible to move whole projects (ie. source code with change history) to a new project to use all new templates for work items.

Comment: You may be able to branch at the team project level (the ui isn't greyed out for me, but i've never tried doing it) to a totally new team project.  The history will stick around as long as you don't delete the old team project.  However it may cause branching issues in the future as you can't branch inside a branch to my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look to http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/ ?
I used that several times to migrate upgraded TFS2008 projects into TFS2010 to use the new templates. You can also create work item mappings to get them migrated too, so that the checkins will not lose the work item relations.
Small disadvantage is, that the history is flatten down to the date of the migration. I "solved" this by editing the adapter to insert the old checkin date into the comment.